# What Jersey version do I need to download for JDK 1.9?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, java-9

I am using jdk 1.9. I am trying to bring up a simple ReST service. Created the project using the maven archetype: `jersey-quickstart-webapp`. Then I went ahead and modified the pom.xml and web.xml. My maven config is as shown below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>restWebService</groupId>
    <artifactId>restWebService</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restWebService</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>restWebService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>6.0_BETA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20170516</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

And the web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>restWebService</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I try to hit this URL: http://localhost:8080/webapi/myresource - I see the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:500)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Root Cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
    jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner$1.f(FileSchemeScanner.java:86)
    com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
```

When I change the build configuration from 1.9 to 1.8

```
<configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
```

the service comes up without any issues and I see the expected result on the browser.

I am using Intellij, Project SDK - 9, Project Language Level - 9

What jars should I import in order to make it work with 1.9 ? Or do I need to change maven configuration to make it work ?

EDIT: Dependency Tree

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building restWebService 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact javax.xml:jaxb-api:jar:2.1 has been relocated to javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ restWebService ---
[WARNING] The artifact javax.xml:jaxb-api:jar:2.1 has been relocated to javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1
[INFO] restWebService:restWebService:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:jar:1.19.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.19.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:6.0_BETA:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20170516:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.19.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.910 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-14T22:05:15-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/44M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem that current Jersey has a shaded asm 5 dependency, which doesn't work with Java 9 bytecode. Looks like Jersey 1.x is not adopted to Java 9 and it's unclear if this support is coming at all. As a temporary solution, I made a [branch](https://github.com/Spikhalskiy/jersey-1.x/tree/asm-6.0) where I deleted shaded asm, migrated packages in code to use a regular asm dependency and put asm 6.0 in maven dependencies.

You can build only jersey-server and jersey-servlet modules from this branch because only these two depend on asm and use these two custom artifacts in your project.

My projects work fine with such a replacement, but I can't guarantee that it's 100% working solution, I wasn't able to build the whole distribution without fails and can't invest time for a full adoption and check right now. On the same time, the main Jersey parts built without issues.

So, your final pom would look like:

```
<!--regular jersey dependencies with the last 1.19.4 version-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>${custom-jersey-with-asm6.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
     <version>${custom-jersey-with-asm6.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
     <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
     <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few artifacts that you might need to update. To start with you shall check your module's `mvn dependency:tree` to look out for any source of `asm` that brings in version `< 6.0.x` since that is not compatible with Java9. From the current `pom.xml` and as inferred from your execution logs, you can update

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Importantly, use [Java 9 compatible maven plugins](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+9+-+Jigsaw) such as -

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <source>9</source>
        <target>9</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

On a side note, you might end up still facing some other challenges(I can see conflicting `jaxb` dependencies, even `asm` might be transitive from `jersey`) to resolve which you shall run

```
mvn dependency:analyze
```

and make sure that conflicting dependencies are excluded in such cases to make use of their updated version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I see the same error after incorporating your changes in the pom.xml

Comment: @RahulDevMishra Did you try and figure out the dependency tree not bringing `asm` from any other source as mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Let me do it now

Comment: I have updated my answer with the dependency tree. asm is being imported from 6.0_BETA

Comment: @RahulDevMishra If the tree is complete, could you update the question with a minimal reproducible code and do make sure the stacktrace shared in the question is also complete.

Comment: Yes, that is the complete dependency tree. I have updated my question with the entire pom.xml. Also added these in the question: `Created the project using the maven archetype: `jersey-quickstart-webapp`. Then I went ahead and modified the pom.xml and web.xml.`

Comment: ASM throws llegalArgumentException when asked to read a class file with a version newer that it understands. So I think the comments are on the right track. However, if you look closely at the stack frames `jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>` for example,  then it looks Jersey has re-packaged ASM. So I thin you will need to find a version of Jersey that includes ASM 6 (needed to parse version 53.0 class files).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs. I am not finding the right version of Jersey. I thought the latest version available on Maven Central would work which at the moment is 1.19.4.

Comment: @RahulDevMishra You can analyze the jersey dependency and probably custom build it using 6.0 asm to make sure you get rid of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error and in my case it had nothing to do with the version of Jersey. It was due to some elastic-search jars namely (elastic-search, elastic-search-core and log4j.2.1.1) that were multi-release jars. Multi-release jars have a folder named version that has some artifacts inside the META-INF. I deleted that folder and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is jersey 1.x  family max support is upto java 8.

if you try to run jersey 1.x with java 9 or above version you will get the error bcoz of compatibility.

reason is Opcodes.V1_8 in classReader class of jersey-server.

```
 public ClassReader(final byte[] b, final int off, final int len) {
        this.b = b;
        // checks the class version
        if (readShort(off + 6) > Opcodes.V1_8) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

SO in this Opcodes.V1_8 represents the constant value for the Java class file version 1.8, which corresponds to Java SE 8. In other words, it's checking if the class file being read has a class file version greater than Java SE 8, and if so, it throws an IllegalArgumentException.

SO conclusion is you need jersey 2.x family for above versions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).